# Laravel 4 - radio buttons wont validate when using the "sometimes|required" rules

Tags: php, forms, validation, laravel

I am having a problem and I’m wondering if its a bug or something thats just not implemented yet because its very simple.

I have created a 3 step form and I am using Sometimes|required (piped validation rules) and everything else gets validated when present in form submissions apart from check boxes and radio buttons, they are ignored but I still need them to be required. If I take out the sometimes rule then obviously the field is required in step 1 even if the field is in step 3’s form. Again, its a 3 step form so I need the radio and checkbox to be required just not in every step, only the step they are in.

Is there another way to write a custom validation to require the check box and radio button sometimes WITHOUT using the Sometimes validation rule? (I'm thinking using a different method of validation might help)

My View

```
@foreach($rooms as $room)
    {{ HTML::image($room->pic1, "the pic alt", array('width'=>'100', 'class'=> 'img-responsive')) }}

    {{ Form::radio('chosen_room', $room->id, false, array('class'=>'roomradio')) }}
    <h5>{{ $room->room_name }}</h5>  
@endforeach
```

My Model with the Rules

```
class Reservation extends Eloquent {

protected $fillable = array(
'checkin', 'checkout', 'number_of_adults', 'number_of_kids_b6', 'number_of_kids6_15', 'chosen_room', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'termsAgree');

public static $rules = array(

    'checkin'=>'sometimes|required|date_format:"Y-m-d"',
    'checkout'=>'sometimes|required|date_format:"Y-m-d"',
    'number_of_adults'=>'sometimes|required|integer',
    'number_of_kids_b6'=>'integer',
    'number_of_kids6_15'=>'integer',
    'chosen_room'=>'sometimes|required|integer|in:15,16,17,18,19,20,21',
    'first_name'=> 'sometimes|required|alpha',
    'last_name'=> 'sometimes|required|alpha',
    'email' => 'email|sometimes|required',
    'termsAgree' => 'sometimes|accepted'
);

public function category(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Room');
}
```

}

My Controller

```
  public function step2() {

  $validator = Validator::make($data = Input::all(), Reservation::$rules);

  if ($validator->passes())
  {
    $room_id = intval(Input::get('chosen_room'));

    Session::Put('chosenroom', $room_id);

    // do some other stuff

    return View::make('reservations.step3');
  }

return Redirect::back()
        ->withErrors($validator)
        ->with('message', 'Something went wrong, please review your input')
        ->withInput();
}
```

Comment: You should post your solution from here and accept it as the right answer: http://laravel.io/forum/07-10-2014-radio-buttons-wont-validate-when-using-the-sometimesrequired-rule It helped me out!

Comment: i don't think i got a solution.... maybe laravel 5 fixes that problem hopefully...

Comment: The hidden field with the same element name is a great workaround, at least.